# How to set automatic indentation to move past numbers on first line?

Tags: auto-fill-mode, adaptive-fill-mode

I'm using `auto-fill-mode` with `indented-text-mode` to write numbered lists.  I'm trying to figure out how to persuade the automatic indentation to move past an item number on the first line.  I'm working with `emacs -q` and I have `fill-column` set to 70 (the default).  I'm editing this line:

```
 2. Every value-projection function in `value.h` fails in the same way: by
```

When I place the cursor at the end of the line and hit the space bar, I am hoping for the buffer to become like this, where the second line is indented past the `2.`:

```
 2. Every value-projection function in `value.h` fails in the same
    way: by
```

But instead, the second line is indented to the 2:

```
 2. Every value-projection function in `value.h` fails in the same
 way: by
```

I have gotten as far as discovering the existence of `adaptive-fill-first-line-regexp`, but I have not figured out how to use it effectively---and I have a sneaking suspicion that it is actually intended to solve another problem.

How can I customize the automatic indentation to work the way I want?

Comment: Use Org mode lists?

Comment: Yep, it's complicated. Hopefully someone here will give you a clear and helpful answer. See also the Emacs manual, node [Adaptive Fill](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Adaptive-Fill.html). And I too find this use case not handled well. But maybe I to am missing something. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I customized variable `adaptive-fill-regexp` by adding `0-9.` to the big character class.  We'll see how it works out, but preliminary results look promising.